# Adding the first 5 values to compute offset

Tags: javascript, node-red

I am using node-red to get the signal of my load cell. I receive the value of the load cell using MQTT (from my python script), then I would like to save the first 5 value coming from MQTT to compute the offset of my load cell. Then when I will have my offset, I can subtract it from my `msg.payload` to set the load cell to 0.

I have tried to make a while loop to accumulate the first 5 value but the result is updating even if the first 5 values are gone. It looks like it applied the computation that is inside my loop even if the loop is over.

```
var offset0 = 0;
var i = 0;


while (i < 5) {
    offset0 = parseFloat(msg.payload) + offset0;
    i = i + 1;
}
offset0 = offset0 / 5;


msg.payload = offset0;
return msg;
```

`msg` is updating after each new coming from my load cell... or I'd like to keep only the first 5 values (5 is for making a test, then I'd like to use more than 5 points).

For example, here is the data I get from my load cell :

```
1.93, 1.94, 1.95, 1.94, 1.96, 1.93, 1.88, 1.93.
```

It should take the first 5 :

```
1.93, 1.94, 1.95, 1.94, 1.96
```

And make the mean.

Comment: do you have some data for `msg` and the wanted outcome?

Comment: I make an update of my post to show the data. @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your approach.

First,by default the function node (where your code is running) doesn't keep any state. This means that `offset0` will be reset to 0 for every incoming message.

Second, the code is triggered by an incoming message, this means that `while()` loop will always run with the  same value (what ever was in `msg.payload` for the message that triggered the node)

You need to make use of what is known as the [context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#storing-data) to store values between messages arriving at the function node.

Something a like this should be a starting point:

```
//get current offset array from context or empty array
var offset = context.get('offset') || [];

//if less than 5 readings store value and do not send on message
if (offset.length < 5) {
  offset.push(msg.payload);
  context.set('offset',offset);
  return;
} else {
  //otherwise calculate mean and remove from value and forward.
  var o;
  for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    o += offset[i];
  }
  msg.payload = msg.payload - (o/5);
  return msg;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. It means that now I can access offset from another node ?

Comment: Yes, read the linked doc about the 3 different levels of context store (node, flow, context)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a remainder of the index and reset `sum` on zero and get the mean of the last five on four.

```js
var values = [1.93, 1.94, 1.95, 1.94, 1.96, 1.93, 1.88, 1.93],
    sum = 0,
    count = 0,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0) sum = 0;         // reset
    sum += values[i];
    if (i % 5 === 4) {                // take mean
        console.log(sum / 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't really work in a Node-RED function node because the values are not known ahead of time, and we need to use the context to store values between messages.